# In C converting from a if else to Switch

Tags: c, switch-statement

With everyone's help I have re-edited my code. I updated my question: How can I increase the states with the switch construct. I placed the [((button_in & 0x0040) != 0)] expression in for the switch (expr). This gave me the first two states that I was intending. (1) Press button 1 yields 0001. (2) Press button 2 yields 0010. I am not exactly sure on how to program Press button 1 TWICE in order to yield 0010. I could use a hint or a point in the right direction. I have been working on this all day and I feel that the problem is related to the switch's expression. Thank you

```
int main()
{
char state;
char A;
int button_in = 0; 
DeviceInit();   //set LED1 thru LED4 as digital output
DelayInit();    //Initialize timer for delay

while(1)
{
button_in = PORTReadBits (IOPORT_A, BIT_6 | BIT_7);
if (button_in != 0)
{
    switch ((button_in & 0x0040) != 0)
    {
    case 0: ((button_in & 0x0040) != 0);  //1. Press button1. State goes to 001.
                 PORTWrite (IOPORT_B, BIT_11);
                 break;

    default: //((button_in & 0x0080) != 0); //2. Press button2. State goes to 010
                 PORTWrite (IOPORT_B, BIT_10);
                 break;
    }

    DelayMs(100);
    PORTClearBits(IOPORT_B, BIT_10 | BIT_11 | BIT_12 | BIT_13);
    //Add Breakpoint here
}
}
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Statements between `switch()` and the first `case` will not be executed, since `switch` jumps directly to the matching `case` statement.

Comment: So it never sets `button_in`

Comment: Where exactly do you set `state`?

Comment: `DelayMs(100);` looks like a long time ;-) 100 Mega-seconds.

Comment: @chux- It should look like Delayms(100) mostly

Answer (score 6):

The code has a malformed switch statement.  Write it like this:

```
int main()
{
    char state;
    int button_in = 0;
    DeviceInit();
    DelayInit();

    button_in = PORTReadBits (IOPORT_A, BIT_6 | BIT_7);
    if (button_in != 0)
    {
        switch (state)
        {
        case 'A': if ((button_in & 0x0040) != 0)  //1. Press button1. State goes to 001.
                     PORTWrite(IOPORT_B, BIT_10);
                  break;
        case 'B': if ((button_in & 0x0080) != 0) //1aaab. Press button2. State goes to 1000
                    PORTWrite (IOPORT_B, BIT_13);
                  break;
        }

        DelayMs(100);
        PORTCLearBits(IOPORT_B, BIT_10 | BIT_11 | BIT_12 | BIT_13);
        //Add Breakpoint here
    }
}
```

Comment: Note `state` not initialized nor assigned before use in  `switch (state)`.

Comment: @chux:  Yep.  I figure that will take care of itself once the OP tries to run it.

Comment: True that OP _should_ eventually notice that.  It was more of a note to OP than to detract from this fine answer.

Comment: I ran it. The problem now is that all the LEDs are lit. I will revise the code in the main header.

Comment: @Jeremiah:  Should pushing the buttons change `state`?  I didn't want to guess at the intent of your code.

Comment: @wallyk: I updated the code. When I press button 1, LED 0001 lights up. When I press button 2, LED 0010 lights up. I would like to know how to make it so when I press button 1 & button 1, LED 0010 lights up.

Comment: You could add a default condition to the switch. In case the values read are wrong due to debouncing effects etc. when the button is pressed

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't actually assign any value to "state", so testing it isn't going to give you any meaningful results.

Second, you're jumping into the middle of an "if" block.  There are legitimate reasons for doing this sort of thing (see Duff's Device), but typically it's a mistake.  Did you mean for the "case" to be inside of the "if" instead of vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

The following lines are being bypassed completely:

```
button_in = PORTReadBits (IOPORT_A, BIT_6 | BIT_7); 
if (button_in != 0) {
```

The `switch` statement immediately branches to the first matching case; any code prior to the first matching case label is skipped.

You'll need to move that `PORTReadBits` call outside of the `switch` statement.

Answer (score -1):

`if`/`case` doesn't go together.

`switch` goes with `case`, and `if` goes with `else`.

Read up the basics of the language.